A stronger form of the weak basis theorem?
Let $X$ be a Banach space of functions defined on $\mathbb R$.
Assume there exists a sequence of functions $f_n$ such that
$$f(x)=\sum e_n(f) f_n(x)$$
where the equality is supposed to hold pointwise and $e_n$ are continuous functionals on $X$, the decomposition is unique and the series converges pointwise (assume the topology on $X$ is stronger than pointwise). Is this enough to imply that this is a Schauder basis?
I would assume this not to be the case, but I failed to construct a counterexample.
This problem is of course related to Mazur's weak basis theorem, though if true it would be a stronger version of it (in this particular case), since the topology of pointwise convergence is weaker than the weak topology.
Any suggestions, references to literature etc would be most welcome
